# Sending gps co-ordinates to a server

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I have created an application which will get you your location and someone elses location. When the app is present on both the phones then only they can track other people. I have created a server using WAMP. How do i connect the server and this application which i made. Would like to add a features to it:- 
1. I want to send the co-ordinates of gps to a server. And also update the locations. 
2.On the server side I also want to show who all are using it and their co-ordinates too. Please help me with the code..

Comment: As said above i got a server(made by using WAMP) and an application which determines other peoples location. How do i send the longi-lati of the people using this app to the server.

Comment: I get that.. But the thing is the coding part.. Just a bit of help in the coding would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way

use `HttpConnection` to your server and put location co-ordinates with device id in post data. and send this data to your server. device id will identify the user who is using the application. in post data you can use `JSON` or `XML` to put your values whatever you want as device id, location co-ordinates and more whatever you want.

### edited part coding part you can achieve as following

```
//get device id as following
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String deviceid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();



                //this is JSON part to put your information inside it
                String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\",\"deviceid\":\""+deviceid+"\"}}";


                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // Post method to send data to server
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost();


                post.setURI(new URI("http://myserver.com/myphppage.php"));

                // set your post data inside post method    
                post.setEntity(new StringEntity(postData));

                // execute post request here 
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Comment: I have edited my response you can see and code in you application like that.

Comment: just another question.. how do i get my device id..? and if i want to get the location of several people to the server how do i do that..?

Comment: to get the location of several people who will you use your application, send current location, lat/long to server through your application from android device.

Comment: hey!! the code you gave above will it post on the server or i got to make some changes

Comment: this code is not for server. this code is for android application to send data to server from android device. you have to write other code `(using php if wamp server)` for server to receive this code and to send response to android device.

Comment: I meant to ask does this code require any changes...? for posting it to the server..